# Relative positioning with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating a user story map with tikz but I have problems with positioning.

With

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    box/.style  = {draw, text width=4cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1},
    double/.style = {text width=8cm},
    goal/.style = {box, fill=red!20},
    activity/.style = {box, fill=blue!20},
    task/.style = {box, fill=yellow},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.25cm]

\draw [->] (-1.5,0.5) -- (15,0.5) node [midway, above] {time};

\node [goal, double] (A_G1) {Goal 1};

\node [activity, below left=of A_G1] (A_A1) {Activity 1};
\node [task, below=of A_A1] (A_T11) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T11] (A_T12) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T12] (A_T13) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T13] (A_T14) {Task 4};

\node [activity, right=of A_A1] (A_A2) {Activity 2};
\node [task, below=of A_A2] (A_T21) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T21] (A_T22) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T22] (A_T23) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T23] (A_T24) {Task 4};

\node [goal, double, right=of A_G1] (B_G2) {Goal 2};

\node [activity, below=of B_G2] (A_A1) {Activity 1};
\node [task, below=of A_A1] (A_T11) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T11] (A_T12) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T12] (A_T13) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T13] (A_T14) {Task 4};

\node [activity, right=of A_A1] (A_A2) {Activity 2};
\node [task, below=of A_A2] (A_T21) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T21] (A_T22) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T22] (A_T23) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T23] (A_T24) {Task 4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I produce

[image]

In the first goal column I have tried using `below left=` and in the second goal column I have tried using `below=`. With `below_left=` it places the element left below of the other element and with just `below=` it places the element center below the other element.

I want the left borders to align each other just like

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution with [`forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest). Less is more!

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,trees}

\newcommand{\innerxsep}{2mm}

\tikzset{
    box/.style  = {draw, text width=4cm, inner xsep=\innerxsep, font=\sffamily, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1},
    double/.style = {text width=8cm+\innerxsep*2+.25cm},
    goal/.style = {box, fill=red!20, double},
    activity/.style = {box, fill=blue!20},
    task/.style = {box, fill=yellow},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={
    growth parent anchor=south,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge path={none}, 
    l sep=.25cm,
}   
%
[Time, name=time
    [Goal 1, goal, name=agoal
        [Activity 1, activity
            [Task 1, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 4, task] ] ] ] ]
        [Activity 1, activity
            [Task 1, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 4, task] ] ] ] ] ]
    [Goal 2, goal, name=bgoal
        [Activity 1, activity
            [Task 1, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 4, task] ] ] ] ]
        [Activity 1, activity
            [Task 1, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 2, task
            [Task 4, task] ] ] ] ] ] ]
%           
\draw [->] (agoal.north west|-time.south) -- (bgoal.north east|-time.south);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to also create a horizontal line running from far left to far right separating goals from activites and activities from tasks?

Comment: @Jamgreen Yes of course. Do you want more space between those or the current space is ok?

Comment: The current space is fine :-D

Comment: @Jamgreen [Like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bM7qo.png)

Comment: yes exactly. but actually I also need it between some task.. like this http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jySCPZkngcs/T2DrcIrEscI/AAAAAAAABw4/u1xrp-n0ISQ/s1600/UserStoryMap.png. I really appreciate your help. It's so much better than my own try :-D

Comment: @Jamgreen [Like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hv52L.png) Although I'm not sure about it, it feels crowded. But if you like it, it's fine.

Comment: Can the horizontal lines be placed between some of the tasks? You're right about it being a bit crowded but it's good. If possible, it will also be good with some more spacing between the lines and the task boxes

Answer (score 3):

Will this do?  (I sort of centered things.)

Normally when you leave off the anchor point it defaults to `.center` but in this case is seems to grab the nearest anchor in the same direction. Note, I also increased the space between Goal 1 and Goal 2 to keep the nodes from overlapping.  Finally, I used the anchors of Goal 1 and Goal 2 to define the timeline above.

[image: tikz table]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    box/.style  = {draw, text width=4cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1},
    double/.style = {text width=8cm},
    goal/.style = {box, fill=red!20},
    activity/.style = {box, fill=blue!20},
    task/.style = {box, fill=yellow},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.25cm]

\node [goal, double] (A_G1) {Goal 1};

\node [activity, below left=of A_G1.south] (A_A1) {Activity 1};
\node [task, below=of A_A1] (A_T11) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T11] (A_T12) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T12] (A_T13) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T13] (A_T14) {Task 4};

\node [activity, right=of A_A1] (A_A2) {Activity 2};
\node [task, below=of A_A2] (A_T21) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T21] (A_T22) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T22] (A_T23) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T23] (A_T24) {Task 4};

\node [goal, double, right=3em of A_G1] (B_G2) {Goal 2};

\node [activity, below left=of B_G2.south] (A_A1) {Activity 1};
\node [task, below=of A_A1] (A_T11) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T11] (A_T12) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T12] (A_T13) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T13] (A_T14) {Task 4};

\node [activity, right=of A_A1] (A_A2) {Activity 2};
\node [task, below=of A_A2] (A_T21) {Task 1};
\node [task, below=of A_T21] (A_T22) {Task 2};
\node [task, below=of A_T22] (A_T23) {Task 3};
\node [task, below=of A_T23] (A_T24) {Task 4};

\draw [->] ($(A_G1.north west) + (0,0.5)$) -- ($(B_G2.north east) + (0,0.5)$) node [midway, above] {time};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a new solution I'll try to explain what's *wrong* with yours.

When using `positioning` library, any positioning option means fixing two anchor points, one at reference node and the second on new node.

```
\node [activity, below left=of A_G1] (A_A1) {Activity 1};
```

means:

1. select lower left corner of `A_G1` (`A_G1.south west`)
2. select upper right corner of `A_A1` (`A_A1.north east`)
3. Place `A_A1` selected anchor at a distance of .25cm from `A_G1` selected anchor. This distance will be measured going to the left and down from `A_G1` selected anchor.

A similar procedure will be done for any other option. In following figure, the distance between respective anchors (south - north, east - west, south east - north west) is always .25cm.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    box/.style  = {draw, text width=4cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle, 
                   rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=white, 
                   fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1},
    double/.style = {text width=8cm},
    goal/.style = {box, fill=red!20},
    activity/.style = {box, fill=blue!20},
    task/.style = {box, fill=yellow},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.25cm]
\node [goal, double] (A_G1) {Goal 1};

\foreach \i in {left, below left, below, below right, right, above right, above, above left}
\node [activity, \i=of A_G1] (A_A1) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With this example I hope you can understand why `below left` moved `Activity 1` to the left of `Goal 1`, while `below` centered `Activity 1` below `Goal 2`. And why, `Activity 1` below `Goal 2` is not horizontally aligned with `Activity 1` below `Goal 1`.

But although positioning options select default anchors, you can force another selection for the new node:

```
\node [activity, below left=of A_G1, anchor=north west] (A_A1) {Activity 11};
```

will place `A_A1.north west` anchor at position 0.25cm below left of `A_A1.south west`

[image]

A second *mistake* in your code was fixing nodes measures with `text width`. Although `double` nodes have `text width=8cm`, they are not long enough to cover two activity columns because you didn't considered `node distance` between columns and `inner xsep` between nodes contents and nodes borders. Alenanno's solution already shows you how to solve this point with

```
double/.style = {text width=8cm+\innerxsep*2+.25cm},
```